# Possibly redundant tags: catan and settlers-of-catan

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

We've got a few questions in each... though it's arguable that they both are necessary, `settlers-of-catan` referring specifically to the basic Catan game, and `catan` referring to the entire franchise in general.  Should we combine these?  The distinction sense in my head, but I foresee problems keeping that clarity as time goes on and our population grows.

(Either way, this distinction isn't in use and some retagging needs to occur regardless)

Comment: For anyone reading this nowadays, note that this topic is obsolete. Several years after this meta topic was written, the official name of the game was rebranded to simply "Catan". We had [a meta topic on this](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1324/3389) and now [tag:catan] is the official tag and [tag:settlers-of-catan] is a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I think `settlers-of-catan` is a better tag then `catan`.  `Settlers-of-catan` refers to the original game, but, `catan` could refer to any of the myriad of Catan games.  A question that pertains to the Catan universe could be tagged as `Catan`, but I think those will be very rare.  While our current usage basically only mentions the core game and thus one tag, more detailed tags would be better for if we get significant number of questions about the Catan games.

While I agree that when you first think of Catan, you're probably going to think of the original game, that's not gonig to be the case for everyone.  Settlers of Catan has had three major expansions and other game series like "Starfarers of Catan", and "Catan Card Game" have been launched featuring the Catan name.  If all the Catan games could be played together, I think one tag to encompass them all would be a viable solution.  Since these are actually distinct games, multiple tags would be more precise.

Even the base Catan games plays very different then when playing with the Cities & Knights expansion.  That's why I think `settlers-of-catan` is a much better tag then just `catan`.  Now, do we need `seafarers-of-catan` tags and `catan-cities-&-knights` tags?  Maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines, there is a `board-game` tag and a `board-games` tag.

Probably want to merge these once we get some Mods.

Comment: While I think we have to wait for merging, we all have the ability to retag questions until the end of the private beta.

Comment: ...and boardgames