# Changing "Settlers of Catan" tags due to rebranding as "Catan"

Tags: discussion

Earlier this year, *Settlers of Catan* was [rebranded](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/139774-Settlers-of-Catan-Now-Just-Catan-For-New-Edition) so that the name of the game is simply *Catan*. The expansions were similarly rebranded. For instance, *Seafarers of Catan* is now called *Catan: Seafarers*.

We have the tag [settlers-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settlers-of-catan), which is what all questions related to the game are tagged as. At one point, we had a the tag [catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan) that was describing questions for the entire franchise, but that was [removed per a meta discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/38/3389).

I would like to suggest that we change the tag name to [catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan), but leave [settlers-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settlers-of-catan) as a tag synonym. This way, the tag we have reflects the current name of the game, but there will still be a way for those who are not aware of the name change to find questions for the game. The expansions would be similarly changed: [seafarers-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seafarers-of-catan) would become [catan-seafarers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan-seafarers), but with the old name as a tag synonym.

I do not have permissions to make these changes myself, but even if I did, I figured it would be good to bring this up on meta since it is one of the most popular games.

Comment: I imagine that a lot of folks will still be searching for Settlers of Catan help. We might rank lower if we shorten the tag name. That said, I care more about site quality than hits from Google. +1 from me.

Comment: @Rainbolt Then again, those who go out and buy the game today and have a rules question would be searching simply for "Catan", since that's what their game box says. At any rate, many of the older questions say "Settlers of Catan" in the question title or question text, so people should still be able to find those questions through a search engine.

Comment: A score of +5/0 suggests that it's time to make the change. I went ahead and created the Catan tag. I moved the tag Wiki over to the new tag. I do not have sufficient reputation within that tag to suggest a synonym (and I suspect nobody will because I just created it). We really need a moderator to make this change cleanly. And don't forget the expansions as well (I think we have tags for four of them).

Comment: Right after I said that, someone downvoted. Maybe they should leave a comment explaining why so the rest of us can discuss.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about Google - it's generally pretty capable of synonymization and optionalization.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me, but I'd give it a few more days before making any change. Not everyone reads the meta regularly.

Comment: It's been a week now since the last comment. Given the number of upvotes, and the fact that nobody who has downvoted has explained their rationale, I think that it's time to make the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've merged [settlers-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settlers-of-catan) and [catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan), and pointed the first as a synonym to the second. [catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan) is now the canonical tag.

I took a quick look at the expansions, but there are a number (and I don't play them often). If you add a list of the expansion name remappings (and a link to the new titles for verification), I'll go ahead and make those too.

**Update**: I've merged [seafarers-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seafarers-of-catan) and [catan-seafarers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan-seafarers), and pointed the first as a synonym to the second. [catan-seafarers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan-seafarers) is now the canonical tag.